# Run another script with arguments

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

This is my (windows) command line argument for running my script.

```
C:\PathToR\Rscript.exe Rfile.r input output >info.txt 2>&1
```

I am sending the input and output file names as arguments and then capturing errors into a text file.

How would I do this from within another R script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always the [`system()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.html) function:

```
return_value=system("C:\PathToR\Rscript.exe Rfile.r input output >info.txt 2>&1")

if(return_value==0)
{
  #Hooray, it worked!
}else
{
  #Boo, it didn't work!
}
```